# org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable

Tags: java, apache, hadoop

I want to convert sequence file to ORC file in MapReduce. 
Input types of Key/Value is Text/Text.

My program looks like

```
public class ANR extends Configured implements Tool{


public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(),new ANR(), args);
     System.exit(res); 
}

public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ANRmap.class.getName());
    Configuration conf = getConf();
    Job job;

    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();

     conf.set("orc.create.index", "true");  


     job = Job.getInstance(conf);

 /////

    job.setJobName("ORC Output"); 
    job.setJarByClass(ANR.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
    SequenceFileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));   
    job.setMapperClass(ANRmap.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(OrcNewOutputFormat.class);  
    OrcNewOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job,true);  

      OrcNewOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));  

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0: 1;  
}
```

Mapper

```
    public class ANRmap extends Mapper<Text,Text,NullWritable,Writable> {
    private final OrcSerde serde = new OrcSerde(); 

     public void map(Text key, Text value,
                OutputCollector<NullWritable, Writable> output)
                throws IOException {
            output.collect(NullWritable.get(),serde.serialize(value, null));
        }
}
```

Here is the exception

```
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcNewOutputFormat$OrcRecordWriter.write(OrcNewOutputFormat.java:37)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:635)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

Output key in OrcNewOutputFormat is NullWritable. How can i convert Text to NullWritable or fix this exception another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **`Context`** instead of **`OutputCollector`**.

```
public class ReduceTask extends Reducer<Text,Text, Text, NullWritable>{

    public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<Text> values,Context context){

        for(Text value:values){
            try {
                context.write(key,NullWritable.get());
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aman, it helps, but i have new problem with ORCSerde, context.write(NullWritable.get(),serde.serialize(value, null));   How can i represent ORCSerde row from value?  I don't know which struct i should use then convert from sequence file.